# When i push value to empty array it showing Node js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
exports.OrderPlace = (req, res) => {
  const all_product = req.body.product_info;
  let meta = [];
  all_product.forEach((element) => {
    Ticket.find({ _id: element.product_id }, function (err, docs) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      if (docs[0]._id == element.product_id) {
        if (element.quantity < docs[0].quantity) {
          meta.push({
            cart_id: element.id,
            pro_id: element.product_id,
            quantity: element.quantity + " Asking quentity is not available!",
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(meta);
};
```

> I'm trying to push `cart_id` , `pro_id`, `quantity`. its loging me empty value please help

> Im expecting `console.log(meta)` values like

```
[
    {
        cart_id: "63db8665ba7126c2b35fb231",
        pro_id: "63d025a8eefcf49cdcdd5472",
        quantity: "36 Asking quentity is not available!",
    },
    {
        cart_id: "63dbc2a7fbf7daf48052189e",
        pro_id: "63ce4393c3433881173d1502",
        quantity: "40 Asking quentity is not available!",
    }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: No, I have a different scenario. I want to push unavailable data to meta variable

Comment: No, you have the same scenario.  `Ticket.find()` is an asynchronous operation (which is why it requires a callback function).  If there's a Promise-based version of that functionality, that would be easier to perform in a loop with `await`.  Failing that, there are other approaches you can take.  But overall what you're trying to do is perform an asynchronous operation and get its result, which is exactly what the linked duplicate covers in significant detail.

Comment: I'm unable to think 

Comment: Adding to @David 's response. The `async` call won't work properly with `array.forEach()`, you'll need a traditional `for` loop and make the `OrderPlace` function to be `async`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the whole code block inside an async function, and use await inside the function to wait for the result of the Ticket.find operation.

```
exports.OrderPlace = async (req, res) => {
  const all_product = req.body.product_info;
  let meta = [];
  let flag = "";

  for (const element of all_product) {
    const docs = await Ticket.find({ _id: element.product_id }).exec();
    if (docs[0]._id == element.product_id) {
      if (element.quantity > docs[0].ticket_quantity) {
        flag = "false";
        meta.push({
          cart_id: element.id,
          pro_id: element.product_id,
          quantity: element.quantity + " Asking quentity is not available!",
        });
      }
    }
  }
  console.log({ flag: flag, meta });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I found to manipulate the array of objects is using the array methods like filter, map etc...

Maybe following code helps you

```
exports.OrderPlace = (req, res) => {
  const all_product = req.body.product_info;
  let meta = [];
  all_product.forEach((element) => {
    Ticket.find({ _id: element.product_id }, function (err, docs) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);

      element = element.filter((item) => {
          return (docs[0]._id == element.product_id && element.quantity < docs[0].quantity)
      })

      meta = element.map((item) => {
            return {
                cart_id: element.id,
                pro_id: element.product_id,
                quantity: element.quantity + " Asking quentity is not available!",
            }
      });
    });
  });
  console.log(meta);
};
```